# child component re-mounting

Tags: reactjs, rendering, react-router-dom

I have a parent component Dash and child one Called Team in the render method (both are classes)

in it's render I have:

```
<Route exact path='/team' component={() => <Team currCompany={this.state.currCompany} />} />
```

inside this Team component:

In the render Function:

```
 <List component="nav" aria-label="main mailbox folders">
                        {this.mapstructure()}

                 </List>
```

and the mapstructure function:

```
 mapstructure() {
 

          return this.state.teammembers.map(member => (
        
              
                <StyledAccordion key={member.Id.toString()}>
                 //irrelevant details here
                 </StyledAccordion>
             
        
        
            ));
        }
```

The parent component state updates (not any property that would alter the props of the Team component, and the map is completely redone, recreating the accordion controls.   To confirm this, I did some logging and `componentDidMount()` is called repeatedly every time Dash renders.

Comment: hello, can you share the full components(Dash and Team)

Comment: I don't mind doing that, but they are each about 300 lines of code

Comment: ok, but you share the layout. when it's neccessary code, you can wirte ellipsis like "..."

Comment: https://codeshare.io/2WOKPv

Comment: hello, share the code on here. you copy wrie on codeshare.io

Comment: ....
<List component="nav" aria-label="main mailbox folders">
        {this.mapstructure()}
</List>
.......

Comment: like this style

Comment: Ok, I will put the relevant code on here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

You are rendering a component via an anonymous function on the `component` prop of a `Route`, this creates a new "instance" of `Team` each render.

[Route render methods](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-render-methods)

> When you use `component` (instead of `render` or `children`, below) the
> router uses `React.createElement` to create a new React element from the
> given component. **That means if you provide an inline function to the
> component prop, you would create a new component every render.** This
> results in the **existing component unmounting and the new component
> mounting** instead of just updating the existing component. When using
> an inline function for inline rendering, use the `render` or the
> `children` prop

## Solution

Use the `render` prop to render the `Team` component and pass additional props.

```
<Route
  exact
  path='/team'
  render={() => <Team currCompany={this.state.currCompany} />}
/>
```

Comment: This does work, if i change the component= to render= it stops the constant re-creation of the component.  I was going to add more code from the codeshare but I think even the top line of code illustrates what the issue was.  Thanks very much

Comment: @gregb Well, it was clear (*to me*) from the `Route` snippet and your description of rerendering behavior.  Cheers.